# Uncaught TypeError, Pulling from API (await issue?)

Tags: javascript

I think I may have missed something stupid here. I'm pulling from a quiz API that provides 25 multiple choice questions

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


export default function Home() {

const [questions, updateQuestions] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=25&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple`)
      updateQuestions(data.results)
   }
    fetchData()
}, [])

if (!questions) return null
if (questions === undefined) return null

console.log('ALL QUESTIONS', questions)
console.log('QUESTION 1 OBJ', questions[0])
console.log('QUESTION 1 QUESTION', questions[0].question)

  return <div>
    <h1>Questions</h1>
  </div>
}
```

First two console logs work fine and produce this [image]

when I add in the third console, pulling the question from the object, it initially works inside the browser console, but if I refresh the page it gives me an Uncaught TypeError, see: [image]

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous; you have to handle the case before questions are available. Unrelated but "!questions" handles "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work has to do with when useEffect is called. Prior to popular belief, it's not an exact replacement of ComponentDidMount. Your app is basically trying to access the empty object you initiated the `questions` state to. You can initiate `questions` to `null` and make it a conditional `if(questions) {console.log(questions[0].question)}`

Answer (score 0):

The code within useEffect() callback is executed asynchronously, so you have to make sure your code works correclty with default values (which is not the case now)

Your API call return a list of questions, so it's natural to have an empty array [] as initial value:

```
const [questions, updateQuestions] = useState([]);
```

Now it's safe to work with the variable as usual, without additional checks for null or undefined:

```
questions.forEach((question) => {
  console.log(question);
})
```

or for rendering

```
  return <div>
    <h1>Questions</h1>
    { questions.map(q => <div>q.question</div>) }
  </div>
```